# Как сделать Update для FirebirdSQL в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firebird, sql

Здравствуйте, всем доброго времени суток! В общем есть заполненная база данных Firebird SQL и есть вордовский документ с таблицами, в которых есть необходимые значения. Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать update одного столбца, путем вытаскивания значений из таблиц документа. Подобным образом заполнялась сама база. Я взял кусок кода, который отвечал за заполнение и решил его переделать, но видимо т.к. опыта маловато получилось немножко не то... Точнее ничего не получилось))) Вот код работы с базой (мне кажется, что нужно либо что-то подправить там, либо переписать как-то по-другому):

```
procedure TVagon.UpdateVagon;
  var SS,TT : String;
Begin
  Try
   Form2.IBSQL1.Close;
   Form2.IBSQL1.SQL.Clear;
   SS:='update params set model';
   Form2.IBSQL1.SQL.Add(SS);
   SS:=  '(MODEL)';
   Form2.IBSQL1.SQL.Add(SS);
   SS:= 'values('+''''+Model+''''+')'; {Здесь возникает ошибка First chance exception at $0059168A. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0059168a: read of address 0x00000024'. Process Wagon_DB_SQL_Parser.exe (6116)}
   Form2.IBSQL1.SQL.Add(SS);
   Form2.IBTransaction1.Active:=True;
   Form2.IBSQL1.ExecQuery;
   Form2.IBTransaction1.Commit;
   Except
      Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(TT);
      Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(Form2.IBSQL1.SQL[0]);
      Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(Form2.IBSQL1.SQL[1]);
      Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(Form2.IBSQL1.SQL[2]);
   End;

End;
```

Прошу подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ibsql.active;=false;
Ibsql.sql.cleaer;
ibsql.sql.add('update params set model (model) values (:a)');
Ibsql.ParamByName('a').asstring:=model;
ibsql.active:=true;
Ibtransaction.commit;
```